# Como denegar el acceso a todos los pdf que haya en el directorio

Tags: regex, apache2, mod-rewrite

Estoy intentando bloquear que se acceda a los archivos pdf que tengo en el directorio, lo tengo que hacer con expresiones regulares, usando un rewritecond y rewriterule se que se puede, pero estoy algo perdido.

Habia intentado esto, pero de aqui no paso:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.pdf) [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final después de varios intentos, logré que me saliera un forbiden al intentar acceder a los pdfs del directorio.

```
RewriteRule \.pdf "-" [F,NC]
```